# Finding distinct solutions for the equation

Tags: combinatorics

> Consider the non negative integer solutions for the equation  $$ x_1 +
>  x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 36. $$
>
> (a) How many distinct solutions are there?
>
> (b) How many distinct solutions are there if $x_1 \ge 12$ ?
>
> (c) How many distinct solutions are there if $x_1 < 18$ ?
>
> (d) How many distinct solutions are there if $x_1 < 18$ and $x_2 < 6$ ?

My working:
a) $\frac{5!}{1!} = 150 $

Not sure how to approach this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Using recursion:

Let $f(n+1, s)$ the number of non-negative integer solutions to
$$
x_1 + \dotsb + x_{n+1} = s \quad (*)
$$
then this is equivalent to the number of non-negative integer solutions to 
$$
x_1 + \dotsb + x_n = s - x_{n+1}
$$
for $x_{n+1} \in \{ 0, \dotsc, s \}$, leading to
$$
f(n+1, s) = \sum_{i=0}^s f(n, i) \quad (**)
$$
We note $f(1, s) = 1$ from $(*)$. With this we could recursively evaluate $f$ via the first argument.

Further for the second argument we have
\begin{align}
f(n+1, s+1) 
&= \sum_{i=0}^{s+1} f(n, i) \\
&= f(n, s+1) + \sum_{i=0}^{s} f(n, i) \\
&= f(n, s+1) + f(n+1, s)
\end{align}
and we note $f(n, 0) = 1$ from $(*)$.

So we got

```
  4| 1
   |
  3| 1   4
   |
  2| 1   3   6 
   |    
  1| 1   2   3   4
   |          
  0| 1   1   1   1   1
  s+------------------ 
   n 1   2   3   4   5
```

which is a variation of Pascal's triangle.

From the diagram we read

$$
f(n, s) = \binom{n-1+s}{s} \quad (***)
$$
and this gives the solution
$$
f(5, 36) = \binom{40}{36} = \frac{40!}{36! 4!} = \frac{40\cdot 39 \cdot 38 \cdot 37}{2\cdot 3\cdot 4} = 10 \cdot 13 \cdot 19 \cdot 37 = 91390
$$

b) We rewrite $(*)$ to
$$
x_2 + \dotsb + x_5 = 36 - x_1
$$
for $x_1 \in \{ 12, \dotsb, 36 \}$. So the number of solutions is
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{24} f(4, i) = f(5, 24) = \binom{28}{24} = 20475
$$
where we used $(**)$ and $(***)$.

c) Again we use
$$
x_2 + \dotsb + x_5 = 36 - x_1
$$
for $x_1 \in \{ 0, \dotsc, 17 \}$. Here the number of solutions is
$$
\sum_{i=19}^{36} f(4, i) = f(5, 36) - f(5, 18)
= \binom{40}{36} - \binom{22}{18} = 91390 - 7315 = 84075
$$

d) Now we rewrite to
$$
x_3 + \dotsb + x_5 = (36 - x_2) - x_1
$$
for $x_1 \in \{ 0, \dotsc, 17 \}$ and $x_2 \in \{ 0, \dotsc, 5 \}$. The number of solutions is
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^5 \sum_{i=19-j}^{36-j} f(3, i)
&= \sum_{j=0}^5 f(4, 36-j) - f(4, 19-j) \\
&= 
\left( \sum_{j=31}^{36} f(4, j) \right) - 
\left( \sum_{j=14}^{19} f(4, j) \right) 
\\
&= 
(f(5, 36) - f(5,30)) - 
(f(5, 19) - f(5,13)) 
\\
&= 
\left( \binom{40}{36} - \binom{34}{30} \right) -
\left( \binom{23}{19} - \binom{17}{13} \right) 
\\
&=
(91390 - 46376) -
(8855 - 2380) \\
&=38539
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

The first part is a classical [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem.

For the second part substitute $x_6 = x_1 + 12$ and apply the Stars and Bars reasoning for $x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 24$

For the third part do same as for part two, but this time substitute $x_6 = x_1 + 18$ and then subtract the number you will get from the number of total solutions, which we obtained in part one.

The final part is similar to the part three, but now you will need a little help from the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Answer (score 0):

So I would use the equation $\binom{n + k -1}{ k - 1}  =  \binom{ n + k -1}{n}$ for $n = 36, k = 5 $

Thus it would be: $\binom{40}{4}$

Comment: Aren't those meant to be binomial coefficients, not fractions?

Comment: @Jam: I suppose since it is a new member of the site, this member does not know about using MathJax for equations. Still, one could write (n+k-1)C(k-1) and 40C4 and so on.

Comment: @String Yeah that's what confused me. Even w/o MathJax, it'd be odd to write a binomial coefficient as n/k.